# One who tries out various jobs

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, idioms

I am thinking of when some tries out various jobs till they find their place. A greenhorn who changes work field often like every two week or month and changes to a new type of job.

Comment: *Fickle?* *Impatient*? *Indecisive*? *Absent-minded*? *Broad-minded*? *Pragmatic*? Your question is *far* too broad as it is. What particular sense are you trying to express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few suggestions:

- job hopping
- a jack of all trades
- a dabbler
- a dilettante
- interning